# SQL associate + - signs in one column with amount in another column and aggregate by date

Tags: sql

I have this table:

| date | amount | sign |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 | 200 | + |
| 2022-07-01 | 300 | + |
| 2022-07-02 | 100 | - |
| 2022-07-02 | 150 | + |

And I want this one:

| date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 | 500 |
| 2022-07-02 | 50 |

Comment: instead of sign i recommend you use an integer and use 1 or -1 that way you can multiply amount and "new sign" and then sum them

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
    date, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN sign = '+' THEN amount 
            WHEN sign = '-' THEN -amount 
        END) AS sum_amount
FROM 
    table_name
GROUP BY 
    date;   --TRUNC(date)   -- CONVERT(varchar(12), date, 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this:

```
select date1, sum(sign||amount) 
 from mytable
group by date1;
```

Thank you.